# Is there any reason to make API of type Future[Try[A]] instead of Future[A]?

Tags: scala, monads

Taking in account that any pattern matching on `Future` result matches `Success[A]` and `Failure[A]` (`onComplete()`, `andThen()`) (because they expect `Try[A]` as an argument, directly or through partial function), could there be a case when I would want to say explicitly that a function is of type `Future[Try[A]]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various constructs in Scala which carry *failure* case in them. There are `Option`, `Either`, `Try` and `Future`. (`Future`s main point is to abstract asynchronous operations, an error handling is there for convinience). Scalaz have even more: `Validation` (`Disjunction` and `Maybe` are better `Either` and `Option`).

They all have a bit different treatment of erroneous values. Yet `Try` and `Future` have very similar, both wrap `Throwable`. So *IMHO*, `Future[Try[A]]` doesn't add much information (about the error). Compare to having `Future[Future[A]]` or `Try[Try[A]]`. OTOH `Future[Option[A]]` or `Future[Either[MyError, A]]` make sense to me.

---

There might be sitatuon where you have for example potentially failing `f: A => B` and `g: B => C` and you'd like to avoid creating too much tasks in the `ExecutionContext`:

```
val a: Future[A] = ???
val c: Future[C] = a.map(f).map(g) // two tasks, not good
val c2: Future[Try[C]] = a.map(x => Try { f(x) } map g ) // one task, maybe better

// get will throw, but exception will be catched by Future's map
// Almost no information is lost compared to `c2`
// You cannot anymore distinguish between possible error in `a`
// and exceptions thrown by `f` or `g`.
val c3: Future[C] = a.map(x => Try { f (x) }.map(g).get)
```

In this case, I'd rather refactor `f` and `g` to have *better* types, at least: `f: A => Option[B]` and `g: B => Option[C]` then, ending up with `Future[Option[C]]`.

Answer (score 6):

`Try[A]` represents a *synchronous* computation that may fail.

`Future[A]` represents an *asynchronous* computation that may fail.

Under this definitions, `Future[Try[A]]` represents the result of a synchronous computation (that may fail) executed inside of an asynchronous computation (that may fail).

Does it make sense? Not to me, but I'm open to creative interpretations.